# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [teleop/teleop_key]: can't locate node [teleop_key] in package [teleop]

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I took over a project on ROS and I'm still pretty new to the environment. I'm currently using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to launch a simple keyboard_teleop.launch program but get this error:

```
process[master]: started with pid [27909]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 25d5ccd0-cd3c-11e8-9d38-74e5f9149b23
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [27922]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [teleop/teleop_key]: can't locate node [teleop_key] in package [teleop]
```

Here is the launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <!-- teleop_key already has its own built in velocity smoother -->
  <node pkg="teleop" type="teleop_key" name="teleop_keyboard"  output="screen">
    <param name="scale_linear" value="0.5" type="double"/>
    <param name="scale_angular" value="1.5" type="double"/>
    <remap from="teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel" to="/cmd_vel"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

And the CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(teleop)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp geometry_msgs joy)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp geometry_msgs joy
  DEPENDS
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

add_executable(teleop_joy src/joy.cpp)
target_link_libraries(teleop_joy ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

#############
## Install ##
#############

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
install(PROGRAMS
  scripts/teleop_key
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
install(TARGETS teleop_joy
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

## Mark all other useful stuff for installation
install(DIRECTORY launch
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305540/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bteleop/teleop_key%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bteleop_key%5D-in-package-%5Bteleop%5D/) by [lzheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/37365/lzheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-10-11**:
Do you actually have a node named "teleop_key" in your package? The CMakeLists.txt file you posted compiles a node named "teleop_joy". The answer from @shiv_rar assumes you have a Python script providing "teleop_key", but I'm not sure how that conclusion was arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey since you are running a python script be sure to add it as an executable in order for it to be called.

```
chmod u+x teleop_key.py
```

After that resource the workspace and in a CLI:

```
source ~/"your_root_ws"/devel/setup.bash
```

And then try running the node by itself and see if it works.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [shiv_rar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38001/shiv_rar/) with karma: 46 on 2018-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lzheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/37365/lzheng/) on 2018-10-11**:
Hi thanks for the fast reply ! I did exactly what you told me but I still get the same error :/

**Comment by [shiv_rar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38001/shiv_rar/) on 2018-10-11**:
Hey last thing to try, add the .py extension to the type.

So:

rosrun teleop teleop_key.py

Also:

**Comment by [lzheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/37365/lzheng/) on 2018-10-11**:
Thank you very much, it worked perfectly for me ! Not with rosrun teleop teleop_key.py but with roslaunch teleop teleop_keyboard.launch

**Comment by [shiv_rar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38001/shiv_rar/) on 2018-10-11**:
Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have the issue `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [teleop/teleop_key]: can't locate node [teleop_key] in package [teleop]` because there are no nodes called `teleop_key`.

**Why ?**

In your launch file you launch this node :

```
< node pkg="teleop" type="teleop_key" name="teleop_keyboard"  output="screen" >
```

You can check [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) all the attributes of the `node` tag. The strings you put here are defined by the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Your package is named `teleop` which is okay because you have `project(teleop)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` but you have set the `type` to `teleop_key` which correspond to the name of the executable, same as the one you would type when using `rosrun`. This name is defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` with the instruction `add_executable`. In your file you have `add_executable(teleop_joy src/joy.cpp)`.

Solutions :

- If you want to change the name of the executable for `teleop_key`, change it in the `CmakeLists.txt` in `add_executable`.
- If you don't want to change the name modify your launch file to have `type="teleop_joy"`.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3